# What browsers are supported through Facebook Iframe?

Tags: facebook, iframe, browser

I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere:

If I create a custom page tab for a facebook app, loading my web app in an Iframe within Facebook:

What browsers are supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any browser that supports iFrames and that are Facebook (without iFrames) are supported.

Opera, FireFox, SeaMonkey, Internet Explorer, Chrome and many more should support this.

However it is very unlikely that lynx would support this.